# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Hello I'mm new to coding and I want to make my signin function using redux, but I have a problem with my code. I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

This is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Container, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { login } from '../actions/userAction'
import ErrorMessageBox from '../components/ErrorMessagebox'
import Loading from '../components/Loading'

export const SignInScreen = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const { search } = useLocation()
  const redirectInUrl = new URLSearchParams(search).get('redirect')
  const redirect = redirectInUrl ? redirectInUrl : '/'

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo, loading, error } = userLogin
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate(redirect)
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
  }

  return (
    <Container className="small-container">
      <h1 className="my-3">Sign In</h1>
      {error && <ErrorMessageBox variant="danger">{error}</ErrorMessageBox>}
      {loading && <Loading />}
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          New Customer?{' '}
          <Link to={`/signup?redirect=${redirect}`}>Create new account</Link>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

When I run `npm ls react-dom`, it shows

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzKD3.png]

Plesae help, I don't know what this error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir. I think you made a typo and the error is due to that.
Change `useNavigate` to `useNavigate()`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Container, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { login } from '../actions/userAction'
import ErrorMessageBox from '../components/ErrorMessagebox'
import Loading from '../components/Loading'

export const SignInScreen = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const { search } = useLocation()
  const redirectInUrl = new URLSearchParams(search).get('redirect')
  const redirect = redirectInUrl ? redirectInUrl : '/'

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo, loading, error } = userLogin
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate(redirect)
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
  }

  return (
    <Container className="small-container">
      <h1 className="my-3">Sign In</h1>
      {error && <ErrorMessageBox variant="danger">{error}</ErrorMessageBox>}
      {loading && <Loading />}
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          New Customer?{' '}
          <Link to={`/signup?redirect=${redirect}`}>Create new account</Link>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  )
}
```